# Classic Doom secret: walk backwards, get cool weapon

Tags: doom

I am trying to remember a secret in old (classic?) Doom game. Point is that you start level on a platform/balcony. If player walks forward towards monsters, you'll jump on the floor and won't be able to get on platform again. However, if you turn around, there is a not-so-hidden passage to a room with chainsaw or something else.

What was the name of that Doom version and what was the level number, as well as the weapon?

Spoiler alert:
I remember that episode while watching "Ready Player One".

> There is a secret, where players should basically drive in reverse to solve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In all versions of Doom 2, you can go backwards (or turn around) to get a chainsaw at the start of the [very first level](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/MAP01:_Entryway_(Doom_II)).

As mentioned in the question, if you move forwards, you'll fall down preventing you from getting the chainsaw since Doom 1 and 2 don't have a jump button.

Comment: I'd like to add that with the availability of source ports such as ZDoom, Skulltag, ZDaemon, and others that jump can now be used in Doom. There is also a rocket launcher available in Doom 2 map 1 that could allow the player to rocket jump if playing with the mouse look enabled.

Comment: @Ryan: The part about the rocket launcher is true, but the rocket launcher is actually harder to find than the chainsaw is.

Comment: As for jumping, the problem with playing the original games with jumping is that it basically turns the game into easy mode because there are *many* puzzles built around the fact that you can't jump.